# Display xml as a .doc in web browser

Tags: xml, telerik, browser, dotnetnuke-module, .doc

I have a .doc that I saved out as an xml. I want to display this xml in a .doc format on a web browser. The reason I want to load the xml instead of the original .doc is because there are key tags that I've placed in the document that I want to replace. For example a persons name.

I should mention that this is a DNN module so I have access to the telerik controls and that it's being developed in vb.net. I was looking at displaying it in the RadEditor.

Comment: When I did this, I used Google docs. You can upload the .doc file, Google transforms it. Then within google docs, you "share" the document, which gives you a link that can be placed into an iframe which displays a visual, scrollable representation of the doc.

Comment: This document is a legal agreement for employees. I don't think we want the document to exist outside of company servers.